# Weird input glitch working around didn't work

Tags: javascript, input

So I'm building a site with a few input fields where the idea is to format the price nice and legible using the local format.
Not too familiar with JS, but I cooked up the following:

```js
let minPrice = document.getElementById('minPrice');
document.addEventListener('keyup',function () {
    a = minPrice.value;
    a = a.replaceAll(' ','');
    a = parseInt(a);
    b = a.toLocaleString('fr-FR');
    console.log(a);
    minPrice.value = b;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Minimum price" name="minPrice" id="minPrice" value="">
```

When I made it denser, it was glitching too and I didn't know what the reason was.

So the problem is that the value will be overwritten when 4 chars are reached. Say you keep pressing "2", it'll go "22", "222", "2222" will be formatted to "2 222".
Adding another digit, for reasons beyond my comprehension, results in "2" as input.

I can make it so the back end would format it properly, but then it wouldn't format the way I'm aiming for when the user is inserting their ranges.

It's a bit messy because the value also doesn't respond to 'onchange', as I had expected.

I expected it to not "eat" user input.

Comment: isn't the `toLocaleString` a method meant to take a date object and return it as a string? and you are using it for another purpose [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Comment: @ChrisG [`Number.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't a regular space character being inserted, it's a [Unicode U+202F Narrow No-Break Space](https://codepoints.net/U+202F?lang=en). `parseInt()` subsequently only parses `2 222` up to the first non-digit character, giving you just `2`. You can catch this (and other non-digit characters) using a regular expression:

```js
let minPrice = document.getElementById('minPrice');
document.addEventListener('keyup',function () {
    a = minPrice.value;
    a = a.replaceAll(/\D/g,'');
    a = parseInt(a);
    b = a.toLocaleString('fr-FR');
    console.log(a);
    minPrice.value = b;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Minimum price" name="minPrice" id="minPrice" value="">
```

That said, I would advise against messing with user input while the field is focused. It's hard to keep the text cursor in the right place, especially when the user is editing somewhere in the middle. Better to do this in the `blur` event for example.

Comment: Thanks, @thomas I hadn't thought of the "center editing" nuissance. I'll stick to formatting after user input then.